# Exact sampling of the $\mathbb{Z}^2$ - Ising measure on finite subsets

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-mechanics, marginal-distribution, percolation

Consider the standard Ising model on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ for some inverse temperature $\beta\leq \beta_c$ (such that the corresponding inifinite volume measure $\mu$ is unique).
**For a finite subset $A\subset \mathbb{Z}^2$, is there a method to sample directly from the exact marginal distribution $\mu_{|A}$?**
An attempt to do this is [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05350.pdf), it however seems to be only an approximation to the marginal.

---

It is clear to me that this is possible when considering the conditional measure.
Introducing a boundary condition $\psi$ on $\mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus A$ and sampling from $$ \mu_\psi = \mu(x \mid x=\psi \text{ on } \mathbb{Z}^2\setminus A)$$
can be done using the Markov chain technique 'coupling from the past'.
For $\beta < \beta_c$, one has exponential decay of correlations; therefore, one can enclose $A$ in a much larger set $B$, sample from $\mu_\psi$
for some boundary condition $\psi$ on $\mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus B$ and then
restrict the sample to $A$ to obtain a reasonably good approximation, but I would like to know whether there is a more elegant method.

Comment: You may have a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911162) and references therein. I don't know how easy (and efficient) it is to implement in practice.

Comment: @YvanVelenik thank you for the reference. I will try to get through this although for a person with a physics background this is hard stuff i fear.